# Selecting overriding method java with multiple options

Tags: java, overriding

To clarify- To my understanding, the methods below are all **override** of `Object.equals`. Are they **overloading** instead and I am not understanding this correctly?

I'm running this code:

```
public class AA
{
    private int _val=0;
    public AA()
    {
    _val=5;
    }
}


public class BB extends AA
{
    public BB()
        {
            ....
        }
    public boolean equals(BB ob)
        {
           return false;
        }
    public boolean equals(Object ob)
        {
            return true;
        }
    public boolean equals(AA ob)
        {
            return true;
        }

public static void main(String args[])
    {
        AA a2=new BB();
        BB b1=new BB();
        if((a2.equals(b1)))
        System.out.println("hi");

    }
}
```

**Class AA does not have an `equals`method**

I'm trying to figure out with the second method is triggered and not the first one. My understanding is:

- Since class AA does not have an `equals` method, I suppose that at
  compile-time the compiler wants to run the `equals` from `Object`
  class.
- At run time the compiler finds out that a2 is actually a BB object
  and therefore has `equals` methods that override the method from
  `Object`.

However, what is not clear to me is why the second method `(Object ob)` is chosen instead of the first `(BB ob)`, if the sent object is defined and actually is a BB object.

Would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: It would really help if you could show us class `AA`. Currently the only overriding we can see is `equals(Object)`. The rest is *overloading*. We can't tell what overloads `AA` *also* provides. Also note that "At run time the compiler finds out that..." supposes that the compiler is executing at run time. It isn't. It's the VM that does things at run time.

Comment: @ctst: No, the compile-time type of `a2` is `AA`, not `BB`. That's all that the compiler cares about.

Comment: AA does not have an equals method, edited to clarify.

Comment: @roony: Rather than stating what `AA` doesn't have, why not provide us with a *complete* example?

Comment: @ctst: Yes, it overrides `equals`... but overloading is performed at compile-time, based on compile-time types. If `AA` doesn't provide any additional `equals` methods, then *any* call to `a2.equals(...)` will call the `equals(Object)` overload.

Comment: @ctst: No, your comment from 17:13:18 is still incorrect. The same method is going to be called in all cases, contrary to your comment. Once you've confirmed you understand this, I suggest we both delete all these comments.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `a.equals(b)`, the compiler looks at the `equals` methods in AA. If it found an appropriate one there, it would use it. In this case, AA has no methods called 'equals'. So it steps up the inheritance chain, and looks again. This time, it is looking at Object, and it finds `Object.equals(Object)`. At runtime, it finds the most overridden version and calls it.

*So if it's still just looking for a method called 'equals', why doesn't it find the more specific version `equals(BB)` at runtime?*

`BB.equals(BB)` is *not* considered an override of `Object.equals(Object)`. It has a more specific parameter, and can't handle a plain Object. Imagine the types are part of the name:

- equals_Object
- equals_BB

The compiler picked the `equals_Object` method, so at runtime the JVM will not find the `equals_BB` method, because it isn't looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

Overloads are *not* chosen at runtime, they're chosen at compile time, when the compiler only knows that the object is an `AA`.  Only *overrides* are chosen at runtime, based on the actual runtime type of the object, but the overload selected at compile time is still used.