# Inheritance Behaviour

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class A {

  public void print(A a) {
    System.out.println("A");
    a.add();
  }

  public void add() {
    System.out.println("At A.add()");
  }
}

class B extends A {

  public void print(B b) {
    System.out.println("B");
    b.add();
  }

  public void add() {
    System.out.println("At B.add()");
  }
}

public class MDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    A a = new B();
    a.print(a);
    ;
  }
}
```

Output

```
A
At B.add()
```

Please clarify output.
Reference From 
[Selecting overriding method java with multiple options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488361/selecting-overriding-method-java-with-multiple-options/35488518#35488518)

Comment: If you need clarification, please post your comments on the linked question.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson could you please elaborate the above Question?

Comment: `B.print(B)` is not considered an override of `A.print(A)`, because it can't handle an object of type A. So when the compiler looks for overrides of the `print(A)` function, it finds none.

Comment: Agreed, then how the control passes to Class B's add() method ? Please observe o/p

Comment: `B.add()` _is_ considered an override of `A.add()`. It has the same name, and same parameters. And since a call to `add()` within A actually looks for the most derived version, it ends up calling `B.add()` (in a B instance).

Comment: Got It..Thanks a lot  @Andrew Williamson